# Why does my python code run as expected in the debugger but not otherwise?

Tags: python, python-3.x, parsing, debugging, pdb

I wrote a parser in python3.6; I simplified it as much as possible while still producing the bug:

```
def tokenize(expr):
    for i in expr:
        try:
            yield int(i)
        except ValueError:
            yield i


def push_on_stream(obj, stream):
    yield obj
    yield from stream


class OpenBracket:
    "just a token value, could have used Ellipsis"
    pass


def parse_toks(tokstream):
    result = []
    leading_brak = False
    for tok in tokstream:
        if tok == OpenBracket:
            leading_brak = True
        elif tok == '(':
            result.append(parse_toks(
                push_on_stream(OpenBracket, tokstream)))
        elif tok == ')':
            if not leading_brak:
                raise SyntaxError("Very bad ')'.")
            break
        else:
            result.append(tok)
    return sum(result)


def test(expr="12(34)21"):
    tokens = tokenize(expr)
    print( parse_toks(tokens) )
    print(list(tokens))

test()
```

This example is trivial; the effect should be to add all the digits in a string, including digits in brackets.

A tokenize() function yields tokens and a parse_tok() function parses the token stream. If it comes across an open parenthesis, it recurses (pushing *OpenBracket* onto the token stream), which should have the effect of treating the digits in the parentheses as a separate expression, parsing it and adding the result to the *result* stack.

When I parser code, e.g. on the expression "1(2)3", it immediately ends after the close bracket, returning *3* and in fact the token stream seems to have ended.

When I run it using pdb however, and set breakpoints inside the loop in parse_tok, I can step carefully when it is processing the ')' and the program correctly returns *6*.

I think the bug is something to do with yielding from the token stream in push_on_stream().

Is this a bug in the interpreter? If so is there a good workaround?

I wrote it for python-3.6, but I also tested it on python-3.7 on a different machine with the same result.

Comment: Any particular reason you didn't just, you know, sum the digits? Or if you need to guarantee proper parenthesis matching, any particular reason you didn't keep a count of unclosed parentheses instead of the complicated recursion?

Comment: @user2357112 This is clearly a [mcve] boiled down from a more complex parser.

Comment: @wizzwizz4: Ah, right, the "simplified it as much as possible while still producing the bug" part. I'm a bit sleepy today.

Comment: Because the code I wrote isn't for summing digits it's for parsing fairly simple but not trivial set expressions. I didn't want to spam people with a lot of mostly irrelevant code so I tried to isolate the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Hypothesis

When the `break` statement leaves the loop, a `GeneratorExit` exception is raised which propogates through the generators. `pdb` modifies how this propagates, which is exactly the sort of subtle bug I'd expect it to introduce, causing it to not exhaust the generator that `push_on_stream` is `yield`ing from.

### Test

If we change `push_on_stream` from:

```
def push_on_stream(obj, stream):
    yield obj
    yield from stream
```

to:

```
def push_on_stream(obj, stream):
    yield obj
    stream = iter(stream)
    while True:
        yield next(stream)
```

then this will affect it enough to guarantee the correct behaviour in both cases.

### Result

Bug fixed!

### Explanation

Provided better by [user2357112's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53785152/5223757). *Basically*, `yield from` doesn't work the way you'd think it does; when the generator exits due to the `break` statement, `yield from` causes the generator you're iterating over to mark itself as exhausted. (`pdb` interrupts this, because it's a slightly buggy pain.) This leads to your parser terminating at the first `)`, because the underlying iterator is stopped when the first `break` statement runs.

Answer (score 5):

Your `push_on_stream` doesn't quite work the way you think it should.

See, when the `push_on_stream` generator is reclaimed, Python calls `close` on the generator, which throws a `GeneratorExit` into the generator to make sure any `finally` blocks and `__exit__` methods run. Since `push_on_stream` uses `yield from` on the underlying generator, if `push_on_stream` is suspended in the `yield from`, this throws a `GeneratorExit` *in the underlying `tokenize` generator*.

This immediately terminates the token stream. In pdb, something caused the `push_on_stream` generator to not be collected, preventing this effect.

Comment: I _just_ beat you to identifying this, though not with the explanation...

Comment: @wizzwizz4: Eh, you thought it was `StopIteration`. `StopIteration` doesn't work like that.

Comment: Hasty summary. But yeah; you get the credit because there's no way you could've typed all that after you'd seen my edit (no plagiarism), and your answer's better.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is exactly where you describe it to be:

```
    elif tok == ')':
        if not leading_brak:
            raise SyntaxError("Very bad ')'.")
        break
```

As soon as you hit a right parenthesis, you abort the paring loop, with either an exception or an explicit break.  Simply remove the `break`.  What functionality were you expecting here?

Test code:

```
test("1(2)3")
test()
test("1(2(4)8)5")
```

Output values:

```
6
[]
13
[]
20
[]
```

Comment: This still doesn't explain the behavioural difference in `pdb`.

Comment: That's supposed to end the recursive call. I'm not sure whether it does the right thing, but there was a reasonable idea behind the `break`.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 You covered that part better than I can -- hence my up-vote.  If you feel a need to cover a complete answer in one posting, you're welcome to incorporate my work into yours.

Comment: That code is supposed to catch an unmatched close parenthesis (though the code I gave wouldn't catch an unmatched open one). After breaking it should return a value back to the first parse_tok instance, which should continue processing tokens but it doesn't, unless I step with the debugger.

Comment: @SilasCoker I can't reproduce your problem exactly, but... I've got it. I think.

Comment: @user2357112  I see.  If OP wants the full recursive experience, then I suggest following the logic of a recursive descent parser.  This code isn't quite there.  Push an entire expression onto the stream and recur on that.  The given code pushed only the leading token.

Comment: @Prune Actually, the logic's sound. It's due to how `yield from` is handling the `break`. I've edited my answer.